# Xcode distribution: Getting The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -67028.)

Tags: xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

This is what I get when trying to distribute with AdHoc profile.  (Xcode 5.1.1)

I cannot find what this code stands for.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a simple solution.

i don't know the very reason, but in my case, the HockeyApp SDK was the culprite of the issue.

The cure consist of removing the reference from the project explorer and to "Add files…" again: don't copy files as they already exist, and check the create groups (not create folders).

Clean and Archive again, and voilà!